# Multilingual site - Adding translation but keeping link to old site till everything is ready

Tags: i18n-l10n, multi-sites

There is a old Drupal 6 site(lets say www.oldwebsite.com), I am redesigning it in drupal 7(lets say www.newwebsite.com) from ground up and also on other server.

I know how to use i18n and locale module to add new translations. Currently new website is in English and language switcher is pointing to old website for translations which is on other server. I want to add new translations on new website but keeping it hidden till everything is ready meantime users will still be redirected to old server old website for translated site.

How can I achieve this? Language settings(admin/config/regional/language) does not allow to add two translation for same language. I want to have something like following,

```
www.newwebsite.com     : New D7 site in English
www.oldwebsite.com     : Old D6 site in English on other server. Not used any more.
www.oldwebsite.se      : Old D6 site in Swedish. Users directed from new site to here for Swedish translation.
se.www.newwebsites.com : Want to create this one but will keep it secret till its ready.
```

I have not worked on any translation setup before so I am feeling completely lost. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want a link in every page that points to the translation in the old website? As the language switcher does?